# When loading data it gives an error " InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid "

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, binaryformatter, loaddata

e.g. I want to select a character and save his number

```
private Storage storage;
void Awake()
{
   storage = new Storage();
}
public void SelectChar1()
    {
     numberChar = 1;//byte
     storage.Save(DataPlayerSave);//save works fine
    }
```

on awakening, the number is loaded

```
private DataPlayerSave dataPlayer;
private byte numberChar;

private void Awake()
      {
        dataPlayer = (DataPlayerSave)storage.Load(new DataPlayerSave());
        numberChar = dataPlayer.numerChar;
      }
```

I tried to divide the data into several parts and one large file, the result is almost always the same (sometimes everything works)

```
public class Storage()
{
    public object Load(object saveDataByDefault)
        {
            filePath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/saves/GameSave.save";
            if (!File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                if (saveDataByDefault != null)
                {
                    Save(saveDataByDefault);
                    return saveDataByDefault;
                }
            }
            var file = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open);
    
            var saveData = formatter.Deserialize(file);
            file.Close();
            return saveData;
        }
}
```

There are also similar classes that load data at the beginning of the scene. If there are 2 or more of them, then it gives an error, if 1, then everything works. I tried to set the sequence using the Coroutine did not help.
When loading data it gives an error "InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid."

**dataPlayer = (DataPlayerSave)storage.Load(new DataPlayerSave());**

Comment: What is `formatter`? What does its `Deserialize` method do? Please provide a [mcve] - we don't have enough information here.

Answer (score 0):

if `formatter` is `BinaryFormatter`: [*please don't do that*](https://blog.marcgravell.com/2020/03/why-do-i-rag-on-binaryformatter.html) - it will hurt you; as for the exception: fundamentally, *use a debugger* and step through the code. In particular, if you say that the exception is coming from:

```
dataPlayer = (DataPlayerSave)storage.Load(new DataPlayerSave());
```

then we can assume that `Load` is *not* returning a `DataPlayerSave`. So: *what is it?* We can't tell you, but: you can find out:

```cs
var obj = storage.Load(new DataPlayerSave());
var type = obj.GetType(); // put a break-point here
Log(type.FullName); // or just log it
dataPlayer = (DataPlayerSave)obj;
```

and investigate *what exactly `obj` is*. Note that `BinaryFormatter` is *very* brittle as you change types (rename, move, refactor, etc) - but that isn't even the top reason not to use it.

Comment: Yes it is BinaryFormatter. Previously used PlayerPref, sdecided to learn another way, binaries were praised and I chose it, others did not look

Comment: @Azanai as already said: [**STOP using `BinaryFormatter`!**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide) .. go for one of the [alternatives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide#preferred-alternatives)